# how to cut object from array and put it in object itself

Tags: javascript

I have response object which contain array:

```
Cars:
[0]: {
       Name: 'Name1',
       Color: 'Color2'
     },
[1]: {
       Name: 'Name2',
       Color: 'Color2'
     },
```

I want to copy the first item in the array and put it to object, `Cars` have to look:

```
Cars:
     {
           Name: 'Name1',
           Color: 'Color'
      },
```

Comment: what format is your response? it does not seem javascript or json

Comment: try the function $.parseJSON if you are using jquery and your response is in json: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: your real question is "how to transform my custom format to json/JS", because otherwhise its too easy: cars = cars[0];

Comment: Your question seems to be: "how do I access array elements" and "how do I assign a value to a variable". These things are usually covered in a [**tutorial**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: @florin.prisecariu: It's Json.

Comment: @user348173: The above isn't JSON.

Comment: and also is bad practice to have a variable called cars (plural) holding an object... plural form is used usually used for arrays, to show you have a collection of data of the same type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're depicting things in memory, and `Cars` refers to an array containing objects, and your goal is to have `Cars` refer to just the first of those objects, you can do this:

```
Cars = Cars[0];
```

If the `Cars` variable was the only variable with a reference to the array, then the array becomes eligible for garbage collection. If the array's reference to the other object was the only reference to that object, then that other object (`[1]`) also becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Some ASCII-art might help here:

At first, you have this:

```
                                 +-----------------+ 
+------+      +---------+   +--->|    (object)     | 
| Cars |----->| (array) |   |    +-----------------+ 
+------+      +---------+   |    | Name: 'Name1'   | 
              | 0       |---+    | Color: 'Color2' | 
              | 1       |---+    +-----------------+ 
              +---------+   |
                            |    +-----------------+
                            +--->|    (object)     |
                                 +-----------------+
                                 | Name: 'Name2'   |
                                 | Color: 'Color2' |
                                 +-----------------+
```

Then when you do:

```
Cars = Cars[0];
```

you have this:

```
+------+                           
| Cars |--------------------+
+------+                    |
                            |    +-----------------+ 
              +---------+   +--->|    (object)     | 
              | (array) |   |    +-----------------+ 
              +---------+   |    | Name: 'Name1'   | 
              | 0       |---+    | Color: 'Color2' | 
              | 1       |---+    +-----------------+ 
              +---------+   |
                            |    +-----------------+
                            +--->|    (object)     |
                                 +-----------------+
                                 | Name: 'Name2'   |
                                 | Color: 'Color2' |
                                 +-----------------+
```

Note that nothing is pointing to the array anymore, so if garbage collection occurs, you end up with this:

```
+------+      +-----------------+  
| Cars |----->|    (object)     |
+------+      +-----------------+
              | Name: 'Name1'   | 
              | Color: 'Color2' | 
              +-----------------+
```

Of course, if something else *does* have a reference to the array, the array wouldn't be GC'd (and similarly, if something else has a reference to the second object, it won't be GC'd). But that's what happens if we assume nothing else has those references.

Comment: You really know how to write answers to poor questions. Such effort must be rewarded :)

Comment: congrats for your effort, but will you draw a chart for each poor question found here? i think they should learn some basic codding before starting "the site of their dreams"

Comment: @florin.prisecariu: :-)They aren't that hard to draw, and any time I can help someone understand objects a bit better, it seems like a reasonable thing to do over my morning coffee. :-)

Answer (score 1):

check this: http://jsfiddle.net/romanian/6no49uwt/

```
response = [{
    'Name': 'Name1',
    'Color': 'Color2'
}, {
    'Name': 'Name2',
    'Color': 'Color2'
}]

console.log(response);

firstCar = response[0];

console.log(firstCar);
```

for display of `console.log()`, you will need firebug or some dev tool

Comment: I can't access JSFiddle, your answer is useless to me.

Comment: i need to figure the sharing features of jsfiddle, they changed their policy

Comment: i edited my answer, thank you TJ for explaining it to me